# Shopware Devenvironment - Reinstall ignored Pluginfiles

Tags: plugins, composer-php, gitignore, shopware

I just installed a local copy of a shopwareshop via git. The problem is, that there is one plugin which contains a .gitignore. Which results in missing files inside my gitrepo. If I would have copied the files without git they would have been there. As I like the way of setting up/copying something via git I need to have a way to get back those missing files. Composer install in the root didn't work out.

The Plugin is ViisonIntrashop and the .gitignore contains the following:

```
/vendor/
/ViisonCommon
/ViisonShippingCommon
```

As I want to keep it maintainable I don't want to delete the .gitignore inside the Pluginfolder. So basically my question is if there is any command to reinstall those missing files automatically or do I have to do it manually which would mean I can not automate the setupprocess of the project.

Regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Shopware does not support installing the shop via git. The git-repository is only for development and contributing to the main shopware-repository.

Comment: Hi Roman, I don't want to install it via git. We have a customer who's shopwareshop was not maintained via git till now. Now I downloaded the current serverfiles and put them in a new git repo where we want to develop it from now on. We have a vagrantbox for development and in order to setup the developeenvironment i'd like to simply clone the repo for each developer to the documentroot of the vagrantbox. But the files mentioned in my first post are missing, because they are not in the repo because of the gitignore which belongs to the plugin.

Comment: sorry, my answer should be a comment - because it's not really an answer.
You could just delete the .gitignore form the plugin - or you add the plugin as a git-submodule.

Comment: But if I update the plugin the gitignore will be back. Same if I put it into a submodule, right?

Comment: yes - you have to delete it manually.
Or you could try to add the plugin with the `.gitignore` to your repository with `git add --force`

Comment: Hm, maybe I give --force a try, but these are all not so pretty solutions. Don't get me wrong, I am really thankful that you're trying to help me! I am only hoping that there is a more clean solution :D

Comment: you will always end up with the problem you have, if you try to add a git repository into another git-repository.
This is only possible with git sub-modules and git-subtrees - or with deleting the `.git` folder and the `.gitignore` in the repository you want to include in your main-repository.